# ReactTooltip.hide doesn't hide tooltip instantly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tooltip, react-tooltip

I'm trying to create a tooltip using `react-tooltip` with a close button.
According to the [documentation](https://github.com/wwayne/react-tooltip#reacttooltiphidetarget), I need to use `ReactTooltip.hide` but it doesn't seem to work. It hides the tooltip only if I'm moving the cursor out of the tooltip, but not instantly.

Using React 17.0.2, react-tooltip 4.2.21.

Here's a quick CodeSandbox example to see my issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-star-er2u66

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick fix can be found [here](https://github.com/wwayne/react-tooltip/issues/765#issuecomment-1119129132)

```html
const [tooltip, showTooltip] = useState(true);

<>
 {tooltip && <ReactTooltip effect="solid" />}
 <p
   data-tip="hello world"
   onMouseEnter={() => showTooltip(true)}
   onMouseLeave={() => {
     showTooltip(false);
     setTimeout(() => showTooltip(true), 50);
   }}
 />
</>
```

Closing question.

Answer (score 4):

Try to remove the

```
<React.StrictMode>
    
  </React.StrictMode>
```

form the index.js and volaa!!
you are done.

Comment: This does seem to solve the problem for me, but can you explain why? When I had `<React.StrictMode>` enabled, I wasn't seeing any warnings in my console.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by removing React.StrictMode in index.js file

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a look at the other answers that were given before. Your approach has already been suggested by Hafiz. In order to keep the site clear and make it easy to find answers, we try to avoid double answers.